# Why is the constraint not in public schema not visible?

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a table with unique index in a schema as following:

```
create schema s1;
create table s1.test(key int);
create unique index test_index on s1.test(key);
```

Now, when I query `information_schema.table_constraints`, the index is not shown. Why is that? However, the index is correctly working:

```
test=# insert into s1.test(key) values (1);
INSERT 0 1
test=# insert into s1.test(key) values (1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_index"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=(1) already exists.
```

The database `test` which I am using here is owned by the current user.

**update**

It looks like the constraint is also not shown in the `public` schema:

```
create table test(key int);
create unique index test_index on test(key);
select * from information_schema.table_constraints;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Now, when I query information_schema.table_constraints, the index is not shown*

`UNIQUE INDEX` != `CONSTRAINT` You need to add `CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT uq_test_key UNIQUE(key);

-- constraint info
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.table_constraints;


-- supportive index info
select
 t.relname as table_name,
 i.relname as index_name,
 a.attname as column_name
from
 pg_class t,
 pg_class i,
 pg_index ix,
 pg_attribute a
where
 t.oid = ix.indrelid
 and i.oid = ix.indexrelid
 and a.attrelid = t.oid
 and a.attnum = ANY(ix.indkey)
 and t.relkind = 'r'
 and t.relname = 'test';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo CONSTRAINT](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1682066e2cdd1dffb87a96c96f6ea80d)** - constraint + index

**[DBFiddle Demo INDEX ONLY](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c8ebdf9409524766b60aefd059eeccc7)** - index

Comment: Woops, I never realized that there was a difference between a unique index and unique constraint. I'll do some research to figure out what the real difference is. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting link about this: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAO8h7BJMX5V1TqzScTx2Nr1jH5iUFG8A071y-g1b_kdzpu9PDw@mail.gmail.com **PostgreSQL has chosen to allow a user to create a unique index directly,
instead of only via a constraint, but one should not do so. The uniqueness
property is a constraint and so a "unique index" without a corresponding
constraint is an improper model. If you look at the model without any
indexes (which are non-model objects) you would not be aware of the fact
that duplicates are not allowed yet in the implementation that is indeed the
case.**